# wxPython: program runs but not displaying

Tags: python, wxpython

Before I made some changes to the following program, everything went fine:

### Program before modification:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
""" A bare-minimum wxPython program """

import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None, "Sample")
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

But after I put `frame` into the definition of `OnInit`, the program runs without syntax error but nothing displayed.:(

### Program after modification:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
""" A bare-minimum wxPython program """

import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, "Sample")    ## add two lines here
        self.frame.Show(True)
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App() 
    app.MainLoop()
```

I try to use the debugger and step over the program. It seems that `self.frame` is not defined (not even appear from beginning to end).

What am I going wrong with the program? I'm very new to Python and wxPython, please help. Thx.

### EDIT:

```
app = MyApp()
```

stdout/stderr:
`NameError: global name 'Show' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create `MyApp` (not `wx.App`) object:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
""" A bare-minimum wxPython program """

import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, "Sample")    ## add two lines here
        self.frame.Show(True)
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp() # <---
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: sorry, but things become even worse. I got a `NameError: global name 'Show' is not defined`.